# How do you parse an incoming dictionary in closures? I've got an error: Value of type '(Int) -> [Int : Bool]' has no subscripts

Tags: swift, dictionary, closures, return-type, swift5.6

I can't find the solution to my idea. I get an error. I would like to create a big function that takes an array to change such as `[1,2,3,42,342,34,3,3,2,4,5,2,3]`, a list with proper numbers `listToFind = [1,2,3,4]`, and an internal function. The internal function creates a dictionary with `listToFind` and returns it to a big function where I want to iterate through the array, checking if the `i` (value) is in a dictionary.

I'm getting the error:

> "Value of type '(Int) -> [Int : Bool]' has no subscripts"

after `if someFunc[i] != nil {`

```swift
func myFuncBig (arrayToChange: [Int], listToTakeToFind: [Int], someFunc: (Int) -> [Int:Bool]) -> [Int] {
    var sortedList = [Int]()

    for i in arrayToChange {
        if someFunc[i] != nil {     
            sortedList.append(i)
        }
    }
    return sortedList
}
```

```swift
func createDict (array: [Int]) -> [Int:Bool] {
    var dictToReturn = [Int: Bool]()
    
    for item in array {
        dictToReturn[item] = true
    }
    return dictToReturn
}
```

It's not clear how to return a dictionary and find a value by key in it because going through the dictionary like `dict[i]` works without closures.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a typo so that the `someFunc` parameter should be `([Int]) -> [Int:Bool]` and then you only need to use this function once and return the result to a local variable. Finally you use this variable to check if a number should be included.

```
func myFuncBig (arrayToChange: [Int], listToTakeToFind: [Int], someFunc: ([Int]) -> [Int:Bool]) -> [Int] {
    var sortedList = [Int]()

    let dictionary = someFunc(listToTakeToFind)
    for i in arrayToChange {
        if let flag = dictionary[i], flag {
            sortedList.append(i)
        }
    }
    return sortedList
}
```

Note tough that the dictionary is not really needed, you could let the function return an array instead for all numbers that should be included, thus implying the `true` value or skip the collection all together and have a function that directly returns true or false if a given number should be included.

Finally, with the implementation of `someFunc` you have in the question this could have been written as

```
array.filter(listToFind.contains)
```

Answer (score 0):

`someFunc` is a function that takes an `Int` and returns a dictionary, and so it should be
`someFunc(i)`.

Try this:

```
func myFuncBig (arrayToChange: [Int], listToTakeToFind: [Int], someFunc: (Int) -> [Int:Bool]) -> [Int] {
    var sortedList = [Int]()

    for i in arrayToChange {
        if !someFunc(i).isEmpty {  // <-- here
            sortedList.append(i)
        }
    }
    return sortedList
}
```

Alternatively, you could use: `if someFunc(i)[i] != nil`